# Xcode debugger displays string correctly but console does not

Tags: iphone, string, encoding, nsstring

When I hover over my nsstring in the debugger, apostrophes and special characters show correctly, but when I print the nsstring to the console letters and numbers print fine as before but special characters are scrambled.

I'm creating my string from an array of chars

[code]char utf[10];
string = [NSString stringByAppendingFormat:@"%c",utf[i]";[/code]

If I try to create the string via stringWithUTF8String:&utf[i]; I get an unrecognized selector sent to instance [NSCFConstantString initWitjBytes....

Comment: can you post the code where you are NSLoging the NSString

Answer (score 0, accepted):

special characters will be printed as UTF string.